# How to create a transparent Activity programmatically?

Tags: android, coding-style, android-activity, themes

I want to launch an Activity with a webView as its content from current Activity. This new activity needs to be transparent and webview should be in the center. I looked around the web but only solutions I found were using style xmls. I want to do it using pure code i.e. no xml declarations. if anybody has come across this then please shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered creating a Dialog with a WebView embedded in it?

**EDIT**
Here is what I have in my `onCreateDialog()` :

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(MainFloatOver.this);
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(llp);
d.setContentView(mLinearLayout);
WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
mLinearLayout.addView(mWebView);
```

Comment: yaa, I tried that but as soon as I load a URL in the webview, it gets opened in the browser instead of the webview inside the dialog.

Comment: that's weird, I used this technic a few weeks ago and it was working... Though I was getting a "Web Page not available" every time I tried to use an external link...

Comment: can you show me the code that you are using. For "Web Page no available" you might need to add internet permission to your app.

Comment: I have the internet permissino, enabled javascript, tried to change the WebClient... don't know why I get that... I'll give you the code in an hour when I have it

Comment: @bhups maybe a little too late, but...  Make sure you provide an override for the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method in your WebViewClient.  This typically happens when the url you are trying to load does a redirect.